# How to show masked Image after segmentation with deeplabv3?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, image-segmentation, tflite

Hey im building a react native mobile app. I need to segment objects from an image. I use react-native-fast-tflite to load a tflite model into my app. Nevertheless I don't know how to use the output_data from the model, to show the segmented and final image.

There is one Tensor coming back from the model. Here is a link to the model: [TensorFlow Model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/deeplabv3/1/default/1)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { loadTensorflowModel } from 'react-native-fast-tflite';
import { Camera, PhotoFile, useCameraDevice } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import ImageResizer from '@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer';

function App() {
  const camera = useRef(null);
  const device = useCameraDevice('back')

  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(true);
  const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState('');

  async function segmentation(image: PhotoFile) {
    console.log('Starting segmentation...');

    const imageArray = await loadImageAndConvert(image.path);
    console.log('Loaded and converted image');
    const modelPath = require('./assets/deeplabv3.tflite');
    const model = await loadTensorflowModel(modelPath);
    console.log('Loaded TensorFlow model');
    const output_data = await model.run([imageArray]);
    const bilinear_data = output_data[0];


  }


  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPermission() {
      const newCameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      console.log('Camera permission status:', newCameraPermission);
    }
    getPermission();
  }, []);

  async function loadImageAndConvert(path: string) {
    console.log('Loading image from path:', path);

    // Zuerst skalieren und zuschneiden Sie das Bild mit react-native-image-resizer
    const resizedImagePath = await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
      path,
      257,
      257,
      'JPEG',
      100
    ).then(response => {
      return response.path;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error resizing image:', err);
      throw err;
    });

    console.log('Resized image path:', resizedImagePath);

    const base64String = await RNFS.readFile(resizedImagePath, 'base64');
    console.log('Base64 string size');

    const rawImageData = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64'));
    console.log('Converted base64 to Uint8Array');
    console.log('Size of rawImageData:', rawImageData.length);

    return rawImageData
  }

  const capturePhoto = async () => {
    console.log('Attempting to capture photo...');
    if (camera.current !== null) {
      const photo = await (camera.current as Camera).takePhoto({});
      console.log('Photo captured');
      segmentation(photo);
    }
  };
```